# How do you call something within an ActionListener

Tags: java, swing, url, methods, actionlistener

So I'm trying to call a method within an action listener for one of my buttons but an error keeps coming up saying unhandled exception type

```
public static void randomRoll(final JPanel panel, final int array[]) throws Exception

  {
    final ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(new URL("http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c5/Dice-1.png/45px-Dice-1.png"));
    final ImageIcon icon1 = new ImageIcon(new URL("http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/18/Dice-2.png/45px-Dice-2.png"));
    final ImageIcon icon2 = new ImageIcon(new URL("http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/70/Dice-3.png/45px-Dice-3.png"));
    final ImageIcon icon3 = new ImageIcon(new URL("http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a9/Dice-4.png/45px-Dice-4.png"));
    final ImageIcon icon4 = new ImageIcon(new URL("http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/6c/Dice-5.png/45px-Dice-5.png"));
    final ImageIcon icon5 = new ImageIcon(new URL("http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/5c/Dice-6.png/45px-Dice-6.png"));

//final ImageIcon [] diceIcons = {icon, icon1, icon2, icon3, icon4, icon5};

final JButton dice = new JButton ("Roll Dice");

dice.setBounds(40, 40, 100, 30);
panel.add(dice);
panel.setLayout(null);

dice.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
{
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
  { 
    randomDice(array, panel, icon, icon1, icon2, icon3, icon4, icon5);        
 }
});
```

Comment: Post your `randomDice` method, please.

Comment: I got to work with a try and catch exception

Answer (score 0):

```
dice.addActionListener(this);

@Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a) {
        if (a.getSource() == dice) {
            randomDice(array, panel, icon, icon1, icon2, icon3, icon4, icon5); 
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either use:

```
JButton addButton = new JButton("Add");
addButton.addActionListener(this);
addButton.setActionCommand("add");
```

And then:

```
@Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        String cmd = e.getActionCommand();

        if (cmd.equals("add")){
            System.out.println("from add button");
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok ok  you have to watch this ...
  dont  make the **actionListener** inside **randomRoll**(it can't see it)
  make the actionListener into another method or wherever you want(just not 
  into this method).
good luck..